# Counting multiple LIKE results from multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite, spiceworks

I'm trying to build a query to look at tickets in our help desk system. I would like to search for a few keywords, ie "email" in either the subject or description fields, and return a count of each keyword. Below is a sample table. There is a categories row as well, however it wasn't well maintained so most of the fields are empty.

```
  ID |       Subject         | Description
-----+-------------------------------------
   1 | hellloooo             | can't send email
   2 | email down?           | can't get to intranet
   3 | Phone trouble         | can't check voicemail
   4 | Using my phone        | I don't know how
   5 | Need new mouse        | please replace
   6 | Mouse acting funny    | n/a
   7 | Intranet won't Load   | what's this plug do?
   8 | not getting voicemail | why not?
```

And I would like to return something like

```
Category   |   # of tickets
---------------------------
Email      |   3
Phone      |   2
Intranet   |   2
```

What would the easiest way to do this be?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking SQL questions, it's useful to add the tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax varies between the various database engines. (SQL Server supports things that MySQL doesn't and vice versa, Oracle is totally odd in some ways compared to other DBs, etc.) Can you edit to add the tag for the database that's being used? Thanks.

Comment: @gregorio . . . Welcome to StackOverflow.  The more information tha tyou can provide about what you are doing, the better.  Please include the database that you are using, for instance.  Do you have table with a list of categories?

Comment: @KenWhite: why would Oracle be "*totally odd*"?

Comment: Apparently there are some further restrictions. The helpdesk system we're using is Spiceworks. I entered the suggested answer from Sanjen below, but Spiceworks returned an error stating "SQL must not contain INSERT, UPDATE, DROP, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER, TRANSACTION, REINDEX, PRAGMA, ANALYZE or REPLACE."

Comment: @gregoreo please see my edit, you can use an `INNER JOIN` on the list of categories in a sub-query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Let's see: default `NULL = ''` behavior and non-standard `INNER/OUTER JOIN` syntax are two right off the top of my head. ;-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Oracle **does** support standard inner/outer join syntax (has for decades). SQL Server also get's a few standard stuff wrong ;) (`+` instead of `||` immediately springs to mind)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: And thus my comment about specifying which DBMS you're using when asking SQL questions. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the RDBMS, but the following will work in SQL Server

```
;with cte as
(
  select 'Email' Category
  UNION ALL
  select 'Phone'
  UNION ALL
  select 'Intranet'
)
select category, count(*)
from cte c
inner join tickets t
  on t.subject like '%' + c.category + '%'
  or t.description like '%' + c.category + '%'
group by category
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c548/10)

If you have a longer list of categories that you want to query on, then you might want to consider storing it in a separate table and joining on the table.

Edit for Sqlite, there is not CTE so you can do my example the following way (Updated to use the correct syntax to concatenate in SQLite):

```
select category, count(*)
from 
(
  select 'Email' Category
  UNION ALL
  select 'Phone'
  UNION ALL
  select 'Intranet'
) c
inner join tickets t
  on t.subject like '%' || c.category || '%'
  or t.description like '%' || c.category || '%'
group by category
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fb8c6/19)

Comment: Thank you for the update bluefeet, however when I run it it returns zero results, both in spiceworks and in sqlfiddle.

Comment: @gregoreo did you see the sql fiddle I provided?  It appears to be working.  If you created a version with other data, can you provide the link?

Comment: bluefeet this was the sql fiddle demo I looked at:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fb8c6/1

Comment: @gregoreo please see my edit, the fiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fb8c6/19 I was using the wrong concatenate for sqlite. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft SQL Server, I might do something like this:

```
DECLARE @CategoryList TABLE (Category VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @CategoryList VALUES ('Email')
INSERT INTO @CategoryList VALUES ('Phone')
INSERT INTO @CategoryList VALUES ('Intranet')

SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTickets
FROM Tickets
INNER JOIN @CategoryList CategoryList ON Tickets.Subject LIKE '%' + CategoryList.Category + '%' OR Tickets.Description LIKE '%' + CategoryList.Category + '%'
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: I think @gregoreo wanted not just these 3 terms, but all terms, encountered both in Subject and Description with their frequency

Comment: He said "a few keywords"... I assumed it would be a fixed list he would provide.  I just used the same keywords he provided in his example.  Obviously, this could be scaled up a couple of different ways.

Comment: Possibly, you are right, but I guess he wanted not exactly that kind of solution

Comment: Sajen was right sorry. I'd like to build a list of 5-10 static words and have the results returned.